# Include new data entered each day in concatenate formula

Tags: excel, vba

I use concatenate to pull data together from different cells in my spreadsheet. Since my data changes daily, I want the formula to also change daily without having to manually input the new cell in the concatenate formula.

UPDATE: Is there a way to use VBA coding to automate the concatenate process based on the following criteria? I have a row of data from D4:AH4 that I insert daily based on the new day. When I use the concatenate and the following formula:

> =CONCATENATE(TEXT('Raw Data'!B4,"m/d")," ",TEXT('Raw Data'!C4,"")," ",TEXT('Raw Data'!E4,"0.0%"))

E4 being the cell that changes daily where next day would be F4, G4, etc... B4 = Today() C4 = Text of my choice E4 = is current days data but changes to the next cell daily. Example E4, F4, G4, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but what is a SuperUser? :(

Comment: Oh, sorry! :(  How about if I ask the same question but for using VBA? I would prefer that but again, not sure how to start that process. I guess I would need VBA to search for the last filled row in column D and then concatenate using the criteria I provided below... Would I still need to ask the SuperUser site in this case? Thanks for your time, I am sure you're too busy to be answering questions like this but I do appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Got it! Thank you! :)     So will add a comment below and direct my question around VBA help...

Comment: In your example, today's data would be in E4, and tomorrow's in F4.  Tomorrow, would E4 and F4 both be populated?  Would G4?
The answer to this will tell if there's a way for VBA to figure out what data to pull.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Tomorrow would be F4, Saturday would be G4 and so on until the end of this month. The data for E4 would stay the same... Example: E3 = today's date, E4 = the populated data. F3 = Tomorrow's date, F4 = tomorrows populated data. I need the concatenate to automatically change from E4 to F4 using VBA...  I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

=TEXT(B4,"m/d")&" "&C4&" "&TEXT(OFFSET(D4,0,COUNTA(D4:AH4)-1,1,1),"0.0%")

I use the & operator instead of CONCATENATE, but they do the same thing.  The last element uses OFFSET.  It starts at D4 and moves 0 rows down and x columns to the right, where x is the COUNTA of what's in D4:AH4.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to create a dynamic range using a combination of OFFSET and COUNT.
See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287), or Google for "excel dynamic range".

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! After looking at the offset and count example, I am still not following how this would work for me... Maybe this will help to explain what I need. I have a row of data from D4:AH4 that I insert daily based on the new day. When I use the concatenate and us the following formula: =CONCATENATE(TEXT('Raw Data'!B4,"m/d")," ",TEXT('Raw Data'!C4,"")," ",TEXT('Raw Data'!E4,"0.0%"))... E4 being the cell that changes daily where next day would be F4, G4, etc... All other parts of the formula will stay the same. I hope this helps! Thanks! :)

Comment: Is there a way to use VBA coding to automate the concatenate process based on the following criteria? 

I have a row of data from D4:AH4 that I insert daily based on the new day. When I use the concatenate and us the following formula: =CONCATENATE(TEXT('Raw Data'!B4,"m/d")," ",TEXT('Raw Data'!C4,"")," ",TEXT('Raw Data'!E4,"0.0%"))... E4 being the cell that changes daily where next day would be F4, G4, etc...

B4 = Today()
C4 = Text of my choice
E4 = is current days data but changes to the next cell daily. Example E4, F4, G4, etc...

Thanks again for any assistance anyone can provide